# Edge Detection in C

Tags: c, cs50, edge-detection

Working on an edge detection function. Looking back at my code I think that I have concept / logic down. But the results aren't coming out the way it should.

```
typedef struct {
    int Red;
    int Green;
    int Blue;
} GTOTALS;

// Detect edges
void edges(int height, int width, RGBTRIPLE image[height][width])
{
    const int MAX = 3;

    // Copy Image
    RGBTRIPLE Copy[height][width];
    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
        {
            Copy[i][j] = image[i][j];
        }
    }

    // Gx and Gy Grids 3 x 3
    int Gx[MAX][MAX] = {
        {-1, 0, 1},
        {-2, 0, 2},
        {-1, 0, 1}
    };
    int Gy[MAX][MAX] = {
        {-1, -2, -1},
        {0, 0, 0},
        {1, 2, 1}
    };

    // Loop through each pixel
    for (int Rows = 0; Rows < height; Rows++)
    {
        for (int Cols = 0; Cols < width; Cols++)
        {
            // Hold RGB Values + Refresh Current Pixel RGB
            int CRed = 0, CGreen = 0, CBlue = 0;
            // Store Gx and Gy RGB Values
            GTOTALS X;
            GTOTALS Y;

            // Loop through surrouding pixels
            for (int S_Rows = Rows - 1, R = 0; S_Rows <= Rows + 1; S_Rows++, R++)
            {
                for (int S_Cols = Cols - 1, C = 0; S_Cols <= Cols + 1; S_Cols++, C++)
                {
                    // Check Pixel Validity
                    if ((S_Rows >= 0) && (S_Rows < height) && (S_Cols >= 0) && (S_Cols < width))
                    {
                        // RGB Gx Total Values
                        X.Red += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtRed * Gx[R][C];     // Current Pixel Red * Gx[N][N]
                        X.Green += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtGreen * Gx[R][C]; // Current Pixel Green * Gx[N][N]
                        X.Blue += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtBlue * Gx[R][C];   // Current Pixel Blue * Gx[N][N]

                        // RGB Gy Total Values
                        Y.Red += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtRed * Gy[R][C];     // Current Pixel Red * Gy[N][N]
                        Y.Green += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtGreen * Gy[R][C]; // Current Pixel Green * Gy[N][N]
                        Y.Blue += Copy[S_Rows][S_Cols].rgbtBlue * Gy[R][C];   // Current Pixel Blue * Gy[N][N]
                    }
                }
            }

            // Value = Square Root(Gx^2 + Gx^2)
            CRed = round( sqrt( pow(X.Red, 2.0) + pow(Y.Red, 2.0) ) );
            CGreen = round( sqrt( pow(X.Green, 2.0) + pow(Y.Green, 2.0) ) );
            CBlue = round( sqrt( pow(X.Blue, 2.0) + pow(Y.Blue, 2.0) ) );

            // MAX 255
            Cap(&CRed);
            Cap(&CGreen);
            Cap(&CBlue);

            // Update Target Pixel
            image[Rows][Cols].rgbtRed = CRed;
            image[Rows][Cols].rgbtGreen = CGreen;
            image[Rows][Cols].rgbtBlue = CBlue;
        }
    }

    return;
}


void Cap(int *Value)
{
    if (*Value > 255)
    {
        *Value = 255;
    }
}
```

When I run the prograM most of the RGB values turn out to be 255. I've played around with using different data types and moving around when variables are created but that doesn't seem to help. I've also tried miniature versions of the code and all seems to work as intended but not sure why when I add it together it doesn't seem to give the correct results

Comment: make a small program and show how it work.

Comment: I mean I have created small parts such as recreating just a 2D Array to ensure that the correct values are being implemented & creating a struct and using 2D arrays to give them values to see if that work as intended

Comment: Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: You cannot use a Microsoft compiler with that code...

Comment: You do not initialize `X` or `Y`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you. I thought that when I did GTOTALS X; that automatically sets the values to 0

Comment: I don't recognize an edge detection operator. Can you provide the formula that you use ?

Answer (score -2):

Here is description of [Sobel filter](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Fractals/Computer_graphic_techniques/2D#Sobel_filter)

`// from Source to Destination
int ComputeBoundaries(unsigned char S[], unsigned char D[])
{
unsigned int iX,iY; /* indices of 2D virtual array (image) = integer coordinate /
unsigned int i; / index of 1D array  /
/ sobel filter */
unsigned char G, Gh, Gv;
// boundaries are in D  array ( global var )
// clear D array
memset(D, iColorOfBasin1, iSize*sizeof(*D)); // for heap-allocated arrays, where N is the number of elements = FillArrayWithColor(D , iColorOfBasin1);
// printf(" find boundaries in S array using  Sobel filter\n");

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(dynamic) private(i,iY,iX,Gv,Gh,G) shared(iyMax,ixMax)
for(iY=1;iY<iyMax-1;++iY){
for(iX=1;iX<ixMax-1;++iX){
Gv= S[Give_i(iX-1,iY+1)] + 2S[Give_i(iX,iY+1)] + S[Give_i(iX-1,iY+1)] - S[Give_i(iX-1,iY-1)] - 2S[Give_i(iX-1,iY)] - S[Give_i(iX+1,iY-1)];
Gh= S[Give_i(iX+1,iY+1)] + 2S[Give_i(iX+1,iY)] + S[Give_i(iX-1,iY-1)] - S[Give_i(iX+1,iY-1)] - 2S[Give_i(iX-1,iY)] - S[Give_i(iX-1,iY-1)];
G = sqrt(GhGh + GvGv);
i= Give_i(iX,iY); /* compute index of 1D array from indices of 2D array /
if (G==0) {D[i]=255;} / background /
else {D[i]=0;}  / boundary */
}
}
return 0;
}
// copy from Source to Destination
int CopyBoundaries(unsigned char S[],  unsigned char D[])
{
unsigned int iX,iY; /* indices of 2D virtual array (image) = integer coordinate /
unsigned int i; / index of 1D array  */
//printf("copy boundaries from S array to D array \n");
for(iY=1;iY<iyMax-1;++iY)
for(iX=1;iX<ixMax-1;++iX)
{i= Give_i(iX,iY); if (S[i]==0) D[i]=0;}
return 0;
}`

Here is [the image and a full program](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Douady_Rabbit_Julia_set_with_modified_binary_decomposition_LCM.png)

result: [image]